# In what branch of mathematics does one learn about Dirac delta functions rigorously?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, dirac-delta

I read about Dirac delta functions in a physics book. I am interested to learn more in a mathematics book, but I have not seen this topic in any of my math books.

What branch or subfield of mathematics defines these functions?

Comment: [distribution theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), sometimes referred to as the theory of Generalized Functions.

Comment: To add, the class you would probably first learn distribution theory first would either be an advanced differential equations course or a functional analysis course.

Comment: In my case the course was just called Analysis